# Opera issue with css animation rotateZ

Tags: css, css-transitions, opera, css-animations

i have tried to make a simple css rotation animation using keyframes and transform: rotateZ from 0 to 36o degrees.

```
-o-animation: rotate-r 8s infinite linear;
animation: rotate-r 8s infinite linear;
```

and then @keyframes / @-o-keyframes

I am terrible at explaining this so I have created a jsfiddle so you can understand the problem better:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxTdd/7/

As you can see, the little black squares are rotating. 
One is clockwise the other counterclockwise.

But i cant get it to work in Opera.. I have searched on stacko and other sources but from what i read online, opera should be able to render this just fine..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how to define an opera animation keyframe

```
  @-o-keyframes rotate-l {
          0%   { -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
          100% { -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
        }
```

for best practice and performance

```
.big, .small{
              -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
              -moz-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Firefox */
              -ms-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
              -o-backface-visibility:hidden; /* opera */
              backface-visibility:hidden;
     }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/bxTdd/13/

final code shall look like :

**the html**

```
<div class=hereComes3d>
   <span class="big"></span>
   <span class="small"></span>
</div>
```

**the css:**

```
.hereComes3d{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d; 
            -webkit-perspective: 300px;  
     -moz-perspective: 300px;  
      -ms-perspective: 300px; 
       -o-perspective: 300px; 
          perspective: 300px;
}

.small,.big{
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
     -moz-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Firefox */
     -ms-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden; /* opera */
     backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.big{
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 18px;
    left: 8px;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

.small{
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: rotation2 8s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: rotation2 8s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: rotation2 8s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: rotation2 8s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation2 8s infinite linear;

}


  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
      from   { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      to { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes rotation {
      from   { -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      to { -moz-transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes rotation {
      from   { -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      to { -ms-transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
    }
    @-o-keyframes rotation {
      from   { -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      to { -o-transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
    }
    @keyframes rotation {
      from   { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
      to { transform: rotateZ(359deg); }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotation2 {
      0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(359deg);}
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes rotation2 {
      0%   { -moz-transform: rotateZ(359deg);}
      100% { -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes rotation2 {
      0%   { -ms-transform: rotateZ(359deg);}
      100% { -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    }
    @-o-keyframes rotation2 {
      0%   { -o-transform: rotateZ(359deg);}
      100% { -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    }
    @keyframes rotation2 {
      0%   { transform: rotateZ(359deg);}
      100% { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    }
```

read more here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. with your help i was able to figure out a really simple way, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bxTdd/12/

Comment: yes you can use it too very nice. it would be great if you upvote it too :-)

Comment: i tried but that requires 15 repution and since i use stacko very rarely i only have 5 rep..